# Magento 2 Partial order payment

Tags: magento2, cart, payment-methods

I am using magento 2.2.6. i have two payment mode. that is "now"  or "later". if later is selected, then after placing order, it will remain save in cart, and if now is selected, then order is placed even if older order is tracked in cart. all the order have separate id.

It is like for multiple order i will pay one time only.

How i will achieve this.someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

Magento2 doesn't do this out of the box. If you want to achieve this functionality then you can create a custom payment gateway extension where you can two option PayNow or PayLater.

If they select PayNow you can successfully place the order with the full amount if they select the PayLater then you can create a custom table where you can save quote id and later you can use it when you want.

To create a payment module in magento 2 you can start by magento sample payment gateway module [Here](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-payment-gateway). Make your customizations in it but it will be hard to start from zero instead of that you can go with 3rd party modules and customize it. I found one which may help you with the same. Here is the link [Milople Partial Payment](https://www.milople.com/magento-2-extensions/partial-payment-m2.html)

Let me know if you thought. If I can help you further in any technical guidance.